# gitignore - only include certain extension except for filename

Tags: git, gitignore

I have sql- and bat-files in a folder:

```
ARCHIVE
log.txt
file_1.sql
file_2.sql
file_3.bat
file_4.bat
password.bat
.gitignore
```

I now want to push all *.sql-files and *.bat-files to a gitlab project except for password.bat, because that is where the password is stored. Is that even possible?
My .gitignore looks like this:

```
*
!*.sql
!*.bat
password.bat
```

but that does not work. I also tried `!!password.bat`, but also failed. It seems after a negation `!` there is no way to exclude files again. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the complete file structure of your project where this `.gitignore` applies to?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to git to only ignore `password.bat` but include all other `.bat` files? In that case you only need the `password.bat` line and can remove those first 
 lines. Git will include anything not in the `.gitignore` by default.

Comment: @WillTaylor: Ah, yes, I should have been more specific... There are other files like *.sql too, that also should be included. So let's say we have sql-Files and bat-Files and I want all of them to be pushed except for password.bat, because that's where the authentifcation is stored.

Comment: Ahh I see, your file looks okay. Have you already pushed the file (which hopefully you haven't if it contains passwords)? If so then you need to delete it from the repo before you can ignore it I think.

Comment: It was exactly that...the file was in the repo due to previous unsuccessful attempts and as you mentioned the gitignore does not affect files from the repo. The documentation clearly states that in the [first two sentences](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) so next time I will _rtfm_ with more caution. Many thanks @WillTaylor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patterns are correct and should work. Maybe post your commands here so we can read what exactly you did.

Comment: Hmmm, this is strange. I checked with my private github account and it indeed seems to work. Maybe it was just a typo and I was getting what Germans like to call "rammdösig". Thanks!